# Replacing multiple strings within html content

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, replace

I'd like to replace all "replace" strings with a certain string using jquery while keeping all extensions (.jpg, .mp4, ...). Here is my attempt:

```
<video id="test" controls="controls" poster="replace.jpg" width="640" height="360">
    <source src="replace.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="replace.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="replace.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash"     data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" width="640" height="360">
        <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" />
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
        <param name="flashVars" value="config={'playlist':['replace.jpg',{'url':'replace.mp4','autoPlay':false}]}" />
        <img alt="Test Video" src="replace.jpg" width="640" height="360" title="No video playback capabilities, please use a better browser." />
    </object>
    </video>
```

and the script:

```
var src = "content/test";
$("#test").replace(/replace/g , src);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use that instead:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DJTqf/)

```
$("#test").replaceWith(function(){
  return this.outerHTML.replace(/replace/g , src);
});
```

Comment: Otherwise the attribute container would no be replaced, here: `poster="replace.jpg"`

Comment: Plus my browser still gives me a couple of errors since it's trying to load the replace.jpg, replace.mp4,... files first. Is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: To avoid that, don't set it in DOM in first place.

Comment: I know but the problem is that I load that block of code into my html code dynamically. So I'm using it as a kind of placeholder, load it into my code whenever I need it and then replace the urls.

Comment: You could just then set valids links to empty images/video urls on you server. Honestly, i'd use any other element as placeholder and then replace it with a new video tag with all url valids, setting corresponding attributes.

Comment: So you suggest to just use a <video> skeleton and then just add the <source> elements via jquery?

Comment: Ya, could be a possibility

Comment: here is an example of my code. Could you maybe look over it and tell me what you think?
http://jsfiddle.net/fluttenb/VG5nm/2/

Answer (score 0):

You need this -

```
$("#test").html(function(_,htm){
  return htm.replace(/replace/g , src);
});
```

Comment: @FLuttenb `.html( function(index, oldhtml) )` is what it should be as per the api, but we can use any name in place of that,as i used `_` in place of index.